# Debugging php on ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, ubuntu-9.04

Is there any IDE (linux based) for PHP that can be used to debug? Or any one can help me to configure debug properties/settings of eclipse? Now i am using ubuntu 9.04. i have tried to debug but havn't tried to configure, because i don't know how to configure it. can you tell me the exact way? please help me.

Comment: I'll ask the same question I asked on your previous question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401902/how-can-i-associate-use-pdt-with-eclipse-in-ubuntuterr ) : With Eclipse PDT, what did you try ? Which tutorial did you follow, if any ? What kind of difficulty / error / problem are you experiencing ? (the more details, the more some will likely be able to help)

Comment: i will inform you day after tomorrow, because i am very far from my regular PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ActiveState Komodo IDE 5 w/ xdebug & xdebug helper firefox extension.

** You can use most of the info below for any IDE that supports xdebug **

You need to add the xdebug information to your php.ini.

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.idekey=
```

Then, in preferences->languages->php, go thru the debugger wizard.  Next you must turn on "listen for debugging connections" in Komodo IDE under the Debug dropdown.

Setup the [xdebug helper firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3960) and enter the required info in its config dialog for your debug server, restart firefox and click the icon in the lower right corner to begin using xdebug on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) with [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) (based in Eclipse) or NetBeans.

Working with NetBeans and PHP is really simple. ou can follow this [tutorial](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHPStorm with xdebug. Works quite well :)